# How do I perform JSON transforms on configs in Azure YAML deployment pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure deployment pipelines (YAML),  I want to perform JSON patching/transforms on an appsettings.json file. (ie the ability to insert/remove sections of a JSON file, not just variable substitution).  The only task I can find that even remotely entertains this concept is the `task:FileTranform@2` Unfortunately for JSON files, it only performs variable substitution, not transforms. (It does mention it will transform XML)

What options exist then to transform/patch JSON files in the deployment pipeline phase?

Answer (score 1):

> What options exist then to transform/patch JSON files in the deployment pipeline phase?

There is no built-in tasks/extensions can transform json files directly, but there are two related extensions you can use to patch Json file:

[File Patch Build and Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-file-patch):

> Tasks included:
>
> **Patch JSON Files**: Patch JSON files using JSON patch syntax

[Magic Chunks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks)

Comment: Do these work in the Azure YAML release pipeline?  They both appear to be for the classic pipeline?  I see that Magic Chunks can be executed via powershell via CLI, so I guess that is an approach.

Comment: `File Patch Build and Release` does not appear to have a CLI, and seems integrated to the classic pipeline. So possibly not a viable option.